# Why there are two layouts generate in android studio 2021 windows?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Android Studio)]

Why two layouts generate automatically (the white one and blue one in Android Studio 2021 for Windows

Comment: That is one layout. It is two views of that layout, one showing previews of widgets (on the left) and one showing a "blueprint" or "wireframe" of the UI (on the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CommonsWare pointed out, you have Design + Blueprint enabled, in the image I posted below you can click the button highlighted in red to select a different type of preview, good luck!

[edit] also here is the documentation page for the layout editor :)
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

[highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5WfK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).